# Powershell Receive-File issue

Tags: powershell, path, importdata

Currently, I am using PowerShell version 5.1 in Sitecore 10 and attempting to use the cmdlet Receive-File in below script

```
$tempFolder =  "D:\temp\upload"
$filePath = Receive-File -Path $tempFolder -overwrite

if($filePath -eq "cancel"){
    exit
}

$importData = Import-CSV $filePath

$rowsCount = ( $importData | Measure-Object ).Count;
 
if($rowsCount -le 0){
    Remove-Item $filePath
    Write-Host "No Record found";
    exit
}
    
Write-Log "Bulk Update Started!";
```

but here $filePath  is not returning the file path by using Receive-File.
It works if directly gives file path but need to fetch from upload file option (Receive-File).
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using the wrong command.  See : https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/receive-file  See following for correct command : https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/receive-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35321/okclick-method-through-reflection-is-not-allowed-error-with-spe for it, it have the fix, you can add these config details and it should be working then.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:environment="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/environment/" xmlns:runInContainer="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/runInContainer/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
    <reflection>
      <allowedMethods>
        <descriptor type="Spe.Client.Applications.UploadFile.PowerShellUploadFileForm" methodName="OKClick" assemblyName="Spe" hint="OK"/>
        <descriptor type="Spe.Client.Applications.UploadFile.PowerShellUploadFileForm" methodName="StartUploading" assemblyName="Spe" hint="StartUpload"/>
        <descriptor type="Spe.Client.Applications.UploadFile.PowerShellUploadFileForm" methodName="EndUploading" assemblyName="Spe" hint="EndUpload"/>
      </allowedMethods>
    </reflection>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

It can either be a separate patch file as mentioned in the link or you can add new config with this detail and add into your custom config folder.